# How do I implement this function without using mixed lists?

Tags: haskell, types, existential-type

Let's say I have a function that takes a list of function-list pairs, and maps the function in each pair onto the list in the pair, for example:

```
myFunction [("SOME"++,["DAY","ONE"]), (show,[1,2])] == [["SOMEDAY", "SOMEONE"],["1","2"]]
```

Is there a way of implementing myFunction so that the code I provided above will work as is without any modifications?

My problem is I can't figure out how to implement myFunction because the types of each sub-list could be different (in my example I have a list of strings ["DAY", ONE"], and a list of numbers: [1,2]). I know that each function in the list will convert its list into a list of strings (so the final list will have type [[Char]]), but I don't know how to express this in Haskell.

Comment: You cannot "as is", because the argument list itself already won't type-check. The closest answer then is to use existential types. But in 95% of the cases this question comes up, it is really a symptom of picking the wrong design. So let me ask, why do you *want* to do this?

Comment: Sorry about the "as is" I probably should have expressed myself more clearly, I just wanted to avoid solutions such as "Make a data type A = Int | String, and use that as a wrapper", should have said closest answer.

Comment: As for what I want to do, an example that is closer to my real code is as follows. I have a function openURLs that takes a list of urls. I also have two lists l1=["google","wikipedia"], l2=[("google","zebras"), ("wikipedia","tigers")], I also have functions f1 and f2, f1 which will transform lists with the same type as l1 to lists of urls and f2 is for lists with the type of l2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with existential types

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data T = forall a b. Show b => (:?:) (a -> b) [a]

table =
    [ ("SOME"++) :?: ["DAY","ONE"]
    , (show)     :?: [1,2]
    , (+1)       :?: [2.9, pi]
    ]
```

And run it as:

```
apply :: T -> String
apply (f :?: xs) = show $ map f xs

main = print $ map apply table
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use *existential quantification* to define a type that can hold any value as long as it is a member of the `Show` typeclass. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data S = forall a. Show a => S a

instance Show S where
    show (S s) = show s

f :: [S] -> [String]
f xs = map show xs
```

And now in ghci:

```
*Main> f [S 1, S True, S 'c']
["1","True","'c'"]
```

You won't be able to run the code in your question without modification, because it contains a heterogeneous list, which the Haskell type system forbids. Instead you can wrap heterogeneous types up as a variant type (if you know in advance all the types that will be required) or as an existentially quantified type (if you don't know what types will be required, but you do know a property that they must satisfy).